# Want the search the all the collections taking the Object id in javascript for monodb

Tags: node.js

I want my code to take the `ObjectId` from the MongoDB collection and iterate through all the documents for the query which is written in my JavaScript code, but I am not able to find the logic for that (I am using Node and MongoDB).

Comment: Which driver are using? Native? Mongoose? One thing is a collection and another is the documents inside each collection. You should clarify the question.

Comment: i am using mongodb connector(native), actually what i want to do is i want to access the objectId of each document in a loop and pass the objectId to another query to search(i am writing  the script in node.js)

Comment: Try using Async You access the entire collection and with async do the other querys of each document. https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each